# Change which folder is master branch of remote github repository

Tags: java, git, github

I am new to GitHub and I've started earlier this week.

I am uploading my Java projects to remote a repository as a backup.

I created a local repository within my `bluej` folder, which had `.java` and `.class` and `.ctext` files. However, I've realized after I pushed everything that I only needed `.java` files.

I made another new folder with  the `.java` files only.

How do I make that new files "replace" my other local repository so that I can upload to the remote repository?
 I tried using `git remote origin master` command, but because I did it on the previous folder, I cannot "replace" it with the new one.

Sorry if some of my terms are unclear, I only started GitHub a week ago.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You don't need to create any new folder. Just remove the directory containing the .class files using `git rm`, then commit and push. Then add this directory to your .gitignore to avoid making the same mistake again and use `git add .gitignore`, then commit and push.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git rm` to delete files from the repo, so you don't need to use the second copy to fix this.

[Documentation for git rm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)

You can also use the `.gitignore` file to ignore files, so your class files don't get readded to git, you can also use the ignore generator to make a template ignore file.

[.gitignore tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore)

[.gitignore generator](https://www.gitignore.io/)